# Wait for two async functions to finish then continue in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on an application in Node.js where I'm calling an async function twice, and assign the value to a global variable.

The issue is that I want to use the result of the two calls to do something else, but this something else doesn't wait for the result to be assigned.

Here's my code:

```
var a;
var b;

let x = 'abcd';
foo(x).then(data=>{
    a = data;
});

x = 'efgh';
foo(x).then(data=>{
    b = data;
});

console.log(a + b); // for example
```

How can I wait for the two functions to finish, before executing `a + b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `foo` returns a Promise you should mark your function as asyncronus with `async` keyword and wait for the `foo` function to respond with the `await` keyword.

```
 async function someFunction(){   
  let x = 'abcd';
  let a = await  foo(x);

  x = 'efgh';
  let b = await foo(x);
  console.log(a + b)
}
```

Comment: why the mix of var & let though?

Comment: I'm getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in `async someFunction(){`

Comment: This works but it makes two async processes synchronous. The code will literally wait for 'a' to resolve and then begin the 'b' process. Rather than running 'a' and 'b' at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Promise.all` here, to wait for the two promises and then work with their data:

```js
let promises = [];
let x = 'abcd';
promises.push(foo(x))

x = 'efgh';
promises.push(foo(x))

Promise.all(promises).then(([a, b]) => {
  console.log(a, b); // for example
});


function foo(d) {
  return Promise.resolve({somePaddingData:"", d});
}
```

Comment: A notable side effect of using Promise.all (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is that if any of the Promises in the parameter list 'reject', the parent Promise.all rejects immediately. 

In this sample, if 'a' or 'b' rejects, the `console.log(a, b)` will never fire.

Comment: @CalebThornton In that case, using [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) would be better. Though that didn't exist back when I answered this ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.then()` you can use `await`. 
So this:

```
foo(x).then(data=>{
    a = data;
});
```

would be like this:

```
a = await foo(x);
```

Same goes for the other function. This will cause your execution to wait until the functions return.
Notice however that in order to use `await` you would have to wrap the statement that uses it, or even better the whole block, in a function that is declared as `aync`.You can find more on how to use `async`  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).